# How to fix Label in StackLayout Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, grid, label, cell, stacklayout

When the `Label` moves to another line, the `Grid` shifts.
There is a grid with two `Columns` and two `Rows`. The left rows are connected. They should have a `BoxView` with an image, the `BoxView` creates a border effect. The `Image` must be centered inside the cell and inside the `BoxView`, which is also centered. In the right column of the top row, there should be a `StackLayout` with a `Label`. When two lines of text are placed in the `Label`, the left column is shifted from the top. I'm wondering if it's even possible to edit the right part of the grid without affecting the left in any way?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Kp3.jpg)
There is no such problem in the video, following the example of which I make.
https://youtu.be/tMdHE4UROFg?t=2631

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid rainbow:DebugRainbow.ShowColors="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <BoxView Color="Red" HeightRequest="218" WidthRequest="153" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Image Source="book_casino" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HeightRequest="198" WidthRequest="133" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
        <Image Source="book_casino" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: If you want `Image` to always be at the top of its column, then set its `VerticalOptions` to "Start". Same for any other element you want to stay at the top.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work https://i.imgur.com/o7rnAOA.jpg

Comment: Its not informative to say "this does not work". Rather, say exactly what happened. In this case, what happened is "It moved to the top, but now there is a gap at the bottom". It worked fine to fix the problem indicated in your picture - you showed an unwanted gap at the top. That gap is now gone. You didn't specify that you wanted the image to fill the entire vertical space. Please **update your question with your actual requirements, and edit the xaml to show exactly what you have, to make the image in your above comment.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dug into the truth, it turns out my problem was the empty bottom row of the grid.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid rainbow:DebugRainbow.ShowColors="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <BoxView Color="Red" HeightRequest="218" WidthRequest="153" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Image Source="book_casino" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HeightRequest="198" WidthRequest="133" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label Text="aaaaa" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Image Source="book_casino" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Steve implied, if you want to remove the shift when label move to another line, you should set the `VerticalOptions` of the `BoxView` to `Start`.

**Code Sample:**

```
   <BoxView
                    x:Name="BookBorderBoxView"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    HeightRequest="218"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                  
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    WidthRequest="153"
                    Color="Red" />

                <Image  Source="XamarinLogo"
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                        HeightRequest="220" 
                        WidthRequest="133" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            
            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" 
                       FontSize="18" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't solve my problem, I've already done it. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/o7rnAOA.jpg

Comment: Please help edit my answer and show how you fix the issue as  it's helpful to others who's facing the same problem.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it was possible to improve the situation a little by adding an element to the lower right cell.